# How do I know the members of this in a class that inherits boost::asio::basic_io_object?

Tags: c++, boost

I have this class:

```
template < typename Service >
class BasicIOObject : public boost::asio::basic_io_object<Service>
{
public:
    explicit BasicIOObject(
        boost::asio::io_service &io_serviceIn, CString& fileNameIn)
    :   boost::asio::basic_io_object<Service>(io_serviceIn)
    {
        this->service.init(this->implementation, fileNameIn);
    }

    void wait()
    {
        this->service.wait(this->implementation);
    }

    template <typename Handler>
    void async_wait(Handler handler)
    {
        this->service.async_wait(this->implementation, handler);
    }

    void wait_handler(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    {
        this->service.async_wait(
            this->implementation, boost::bind(&BasicIOObject::wait_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
};
```

and I cannot see what does `this` refers to? I have not found any doc about `boost::asio::basic_io_object`, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

---

Ok, I know `this` it refers to the current instance, but how do I know that it has a `service` member?

Comment: It refers to the current instance of `BasicIOObject<Service>` as usual.

Comment: but does `this` has a service member? ... ok, the question is bad, i'll edit it

Comment: You know it has a service memeber since `boost::asio::basic_io_object` has a service member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best places to look for documentation on Boost.Asio types and functions is the official documentation's [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) section .  This page contains links to types, such as [`basic_io_object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object.html).  For `basic_io_object`, it is documented that it has a [`service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/service.html) protected data member that:

- is *deprecated*, and suggests using the [`get_service()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/get_service.html) protected member function
- is only available for services that do not support movability
- has a type of [`service_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/service_type.html), which is the template template parameter provided to `basic_io_object<>` that must be a model of the [IoObjectService](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/IoObjectService.html) type requirement

Answer (score 1):

`boost::asio::basic_io_object` has `service` member and `implementation` member. Where `service` has type `service_type` and actually is template parameter of `basic_io_object` and `implementation_type` has type `service_type::implementation_type`.